# Is it possible to determine if a vector intersects a sphere by its projection on a plane?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, intersection-theory

As a thought experiment, I was wondering if it'd be possible to determine if a vector (base point and displacement - as in a ray exiting a base point in a certain direction) intersects a sphere using the following algorithm:

1. Project the sphere onto plane that is perpendicular to the vector (thus creating a circle on the plane).
2. Determine if the vector intersects the circle that was projected onto the plane.

All help would be most appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It depends. When you say "vector", do you mean just a point in $\mathbb R^3$ or an object with both a base point and a displacement, needing six coordinates to describe? When you say "intersects a sphere", so you mean one of the points must fall on the sphere (that is, the surface), or inside the sphere, or that the ray extending the vector intersects the sphere?

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. By "vector" I mean a base point and displacement (a ray exiting a base point in a certain direction). By "intersects" I mean that the ray extending the vector intersects with the sphere.

Comment: Yes, it is possible but unnecessary complicated. Normally you would just check whether there exists a "longitude" of the vector such that it intersects the sphere by using equations for both the straight line and the sphere.

Comment: OR even simplier, your check whether one and only one of the base point and the 'extremity' of your vector is inside the sphere.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The algorithm is only meant to provide an answer to whether or not an intersection exists, regardless of complexity. I just wanted to make sure it always works :)

Comment: Why would it be possible? imagine a sphere perpendicular to the ray, the vector sits on. So, from the POV of the vector it never crosses the circle, cause it itself just a point in the center of the circle - which has no connection to the sphere crossing in reality

Comment: @dEmigOd I'm not quite sure I follow. The vector I am referring to is not a point, it is the ray (a line defined by base point and direction).

Comment: @user467005. It doesn't matter. so you have a ray, which is mapped to a center of a circle (like a canonical sphere centered at 0) - it never intersects a circle. And by the "ray" you mean line? (cause sphere in "back" half-space still mapped to circles you can cross)

Comment: Still not following. To clarify, I'll describe a relevant scenario: an observer is looking in a certain direction. A ray (or line) travels from the observer in the direction he's looking at. I want to know if that line intersects a certain sphere. To find out, I set a plane perpendicular to the line, project the sphere onto it, and then check for an intersection between the line and the circle.

Comment: @user467005: If the sphere has radius $r$ centered at $\vec{c}$, and the ray starts at $\vec{p}$ towards $\hat{n}$, with $\hat{n}$ being an unit vector ($\hat{n}\cdot\hat{n} = 1$), so the ray is $\vec{p} + t \hat{n}$, with $t \ge 0$, then if and only if $$\left(\hat{n} \cdot \left ( \vec{c} - \vec{p} \right ) \right)^2 + r^2 \ge \left ( \vec{c} - \vec{p} \right ) \cdot \left ( \vec{c} - \vec{p} \right )$$and$$\hat{n} \cdot \left ( \vec{c} - \vec{p} \right ) \ge 0$$the ray intersects the sphere. In 3D, this is just 8 multiplications, three subtractions and one addition, and two comparisons.

Comment: @NominalAnimal The first test you list is effectively what the OP is proposing: rearranged into $(\vec c-\vec p)\cdot(\vec c-\vec p)-(\hat n\cdot(\vec c-\vec p))^2\le r^2$, the l.h.s. is the squared perpendicular distance from the (line of) the ray and the sphere’s center, i.e., the squared distance between the projections of the ray and sphere’s center onto a plane perpendicular to $\hat n$.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly tell whether or not a *line* intersects a sphere by examining their projections onto a plane perpendicular to the line, but not for a ray or line segment. The projection of the line/ray/line segment onto this plane is a point and the projection of the sphere is a *disk*. If the point is outside of the disk, then there is definitely no intersection, but if the point is within the disk, the end of a ray/line segment might still fall outside of the sphere. For example, consider the ray that emanates from $(0,0,2)$ in the direction of the positive $z$-axis. It clearly doesn’t intersect the unit sphere, but its projection onto the $x$-$y$ plane coincides with the projected sphere’s center. So, for a ray or line segment, you’ll have to perform additional tests, such as described in NominalAnimal’s comment to your question, to determine if it intersects the sphere even if its projection is inside the disk.